# Any alternative to storing user-data in a database?

Tags: database, web-services, database-design, functional-programming

I'm making a web-application. I wanted to know the experienced experts here, how other web-applications such as Facebook, Fantasy sports, [trello](https://trello.com/), [todoist](http://todoist.com) or Google Keep etc store the data of users, not username/passwords, but by user data I mean data like their statuses, posts,  tasks, reminders, due dates, their configurations etc.

I'm of the impression that all of the above examples would need some kind of database operation. So that, when the user demands/changes some value, the program will have to query into the database where those values are stored. However aren't databases usually a little slow to operate? especially since one user will probably be demanding lots of information at the same time, equaling lots of queries into the database, equaling more slow.

Is there another approach those softwares apply?

Comment: Databases should not be slow if configured and setup correctly.  How much traffic do you expect?  I'm sure the sites you mentioned use multiple database servers (in google's case probably thousands if not more).  There are a lot of things to take into consideration depending on your requirements.  NoSQL vs RDMS, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most web-applications have a database to store user information as you described, yes. This isn't slow however - it's the exact opposite. Databases are *optimized* for fast retrieval of large amounts of data, and they're very good at enforcing and tracking relationships between sets of data and querying for specific sets. So most web applications have a model of a front-end, a server back-end, and a server database, with the server back-end translating web requests into database queries.

This isn't the *only* way to go, but other options can be more complicated. The programming language [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), for example, has built-in features for webservers that include the ability to store the program's state between server requests using [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). This allows the server to essentially remember its running program state between requests, and lets it turn multiple requests into a continuous session by storing these continuations and communicating keys to access them to the browser. I've never heard of any other languages offering this sort of feature, and it can require some mind-bending to get your head around how it works, but it does show that the standard architecture of frontend/backend/database for webapps isn't necessarily set in stone.